# can't access play-scala public folder resources

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

For my play-scala project, My routes file has:

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

however, I am not able to retrieve any resource from this folder. For example, I placed a png file calleg favicon.png in the public folder, yet, if I run

```
http://localhost:9000/public/favicon.png
```

the play server can't find the resource. Any ideas about what to look for to repair this problem?

The server also says that tried the route:

```
GET/assets/$file<.+>controllers.Assets.versioned(path:String = "/public", file:Asset)
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading your configuration wrong, the correct request would look like this:

```
http://localhost:9000/assets/favicon.png
```

That way `favicon.png` will be searched in `public` folder, not another way around

If you want your original URL to work, you'll need to change your configuration to following:

```
GET     /public/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```